# Deployment failed due to a keycloak-admin-client dependency

Tags: jboss, dependencies, wildfly, resteasy, keycloak

I've a REST application writen in Java EE (JAX-RS 2.1/Resteasy, EJB, CDI, ...) which has to able to create a keycloak user in the Keycloak 2.5.5. To run my application I use a WildFly 10.1.0 server.

To create the keycloak user I'd like to use an Administration REST API publicated by the Keycloak. Because of that I've added a following dependency to my `build.gradle`:

```
compile group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-admin-client', version: '3.3.0.Final'
```

After that (only adding dependency) when I deploy my application on the WildFly, I reveice an error due to:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003190: Could not find constructor for class: org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.RealmsResource
```

Sometimes due to:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003190: Could not find constructor for class: org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.ServerInfoResource
```

Here is full stacktrace regarding the first error:

```
08:14:14,505 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 86) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./myapp: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./myapp: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003190: Could not find constructor for class: org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.RealmsResource
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003190: Could not find constructor for class: org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.RealmsResource
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.metadata.ResourceBuilder.constructor(ResourceBuilder.java:692)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.POJOResourceFactory.registered(POJOResourceFactory.java:42)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:208)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:194)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:180)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:157)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addPerRequestResource(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:76)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registration(ResteasyDeployment.java:409)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:250)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:113)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:250)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:546)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:517)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:101)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
        ... 6 more

08:14:14,511 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "myapp.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./myapp" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./myapp: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003190: Could not find constructor for class: org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.RealmsResource
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003190: Could not find constructor for class: org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.RealmsResource"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./myapp"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
```

---

## **EDIT:**

It could be important, there are dependencies regarding the JAX-RS/Resteasy in a `build.gradle`:

```
compile( 'javax:javaee-api:7.0') {
    exclude group: 'javax.ws.rs', module: 'javax.ws.rs-api'
}
compile group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'javax.ws.rs-api', version: '2.1'
compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-servlet-initializer', version: '3.1.4.Final'
//compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-jaxrs', version: '3.1.4.Final'
compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-jaxb-provider', version: '3.1.4.Final'
compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-multipart-provider', version: '3.1.4.Final'
```

When I use a `resteasy-jaxrs` lib instead of a `resteasy-servlet-initializer`, I can deploy the application without any issues but then application's endpoints don't work (not found error).

Comment: Please provide the code snippet that you are using to create the user via keycloak admin client API. And tell us where you are doing this (I assume inside the "Application" class that is initializing your service).

Comment: BTW: I recommend to use _providedCompile_ instead of _compile_ dependency for all those "javax" and "resteasy" dependencies. They are all part of wildfly already and shouldn't be in your war file.